# simplexml_load_file() Connection timed out trying to parse remote xml

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an xml file from this url 
http://87.102.127.86:8081/kwiktext/kwiktext.exe?Page=52&compid=33&refnum=ICE2-1713464-220

The ref number expires daily so you may see almost no content by the time you look into it. But this is urelated with the issue.
I am trying to parse it with simplexml_load_file() using

```
<?php 
    $xml = 'http://87.102.127.86:8081/kwiktext/kwiktext.exe?Page=52&compid=33&refnum=ICE2-1713464-220';
    $xml= simplexml_load_file($xml) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

     echo urldecode($xml->hoteldescription); ?>
```

Unsuccessfully it returns 'Connection timed out'.
But when I try to do the same with a random xml url I found on the net the action completes just fine:

```
<?php $xml=simplexml_load_file('http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/PredictionSummary/V') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->Time['TimeStamp']?>
```

Why I am getting the Connection Time Out? 
The providers of the link said that it is a simple task. If I download the xml source from the url on a local file on my server I can fetch it with no problems. So there must be something with the remote request. 
Needless to say that I am a php newbie... especially on server requests. 
Thanks!

**EDIT**
I have also tried file_get_contents() and it didn't work for me. 
 Also the last thing I tried again with no success was this

```
function load_file_from_url($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'mydomain');
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $str;
  }
   function load_xml_from_url($url) {
    return simplexml_load_string(load_file_from_url($url));
  }
  $xml = load_xml_from_url('http://87.102.127.86:8081/kwiktext/kwiktext.exe?Page=52&compid=33&refnum=ICE2-1713464-220');'
```

**EDIT 2**

Apparently the 8081 port that was required from the service was closed on both the servers I was attempting connection by the hosts.

Comment: try using `file_get_contents();` to get the file. Then use `simplexml_load_string();` to load the content.

Comment: I have tried this with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me. I copied and pasted your code and ran it locally without any problems. If you encountered a connection timeout error it would seem to be a temporary error. The only error I noticed was when you are printing the hotel description the property name was incorrect:

`echo urldecode($xml->HotelDescription);`

Comment: Hi, I am getting connection timeout error for days... The fact that you managed to run it with just my code suprises me. I am trying this from two domains. The one at my work and one personal each on different hosting. Both are .gr. Any change we are getting blocked or something??

Comment: That's very possible because the code is working fine for me. I have tried it several times with no error.

Comment: Apparently the 8081 port that was required from the service was closed on both the servers I was attempting connection by the hosts.